# Is it possible to control a video from textbox value in VB based Scada system

Tags: vba

I have created a Scada System in Visual Basic 2010.

This system displays the radial *Gate* position of hydro power plant. I have the analog value of particular signal in a textbox which use for gate position.

Please suggest me, how can I make the radial *Gate* animation, which is related to that texbox values or i have a gate opening and closing video of gate. Is it possible to control the video where i want (reference of textbox values), so that i can show the gate position at the particular analog value?

Answer (score 0):

Try the enabling the "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS" reference, then adding the below code. You can tweak the code to reflect your needs as required.

Code:
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Dim canvas As New ShapeContainer
Dim theLine As New LineShape
' Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
canvas.Parent = Me 
' Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the LineShape.
theLine.Parent = canvas
' Set the starting and ending coordinates for the line.
theLine.StartPoint = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
theLine.EndPoint = New System.Drawing.Point(640, 480)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc488281.aspx